# Sampling with replacement in Matlab

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I have a set of `n` genomes, and `n` corresponding fitness values. I would like to sample the genomes with replacement according to their proportional fitness values, such that `P(genome) = fitness(genome) / sum(fitness(genomes))`. Is there a built-in mechanism for sampling like this in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get 10 samples from a population of 4 whose fitnesses are 0.4, 0.3, 0.2 and 0.1 respectively, then you can do:

```
>> fitness = [0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1];
>> mnrnd(10,fitness)
ans =
     3     5     1     1
```

Comment: This is actually different from what I was expecting but it does solve the problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has built in multinomial random number generator. You can use `mnrnd` for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/randsample.html) for this purpose:

```
>> f = [2 5 7 8 1]; %# fitness values (not normalized)
>> g = {'g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4', 'g5'}; %# genome names
>> gSampled = randsample(g,100,true,f) %# sample 100 genomes with replacement
```